# What (really) happens in HDFS during a Hive Update?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Here is the situation :

1. HDFS is known to be Append-Only (No Update *per se*).
2. Hive writes data to its warehouse, which is located in HDFS.
3. Updates can be performed in Hive

This implies that new data is written, and old data should be somehow marked as deprecated and later wiped out at some point.

I searched but did not manage to find any information about this so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138131/how-updating-data-in-hive-transaction-tables-result-in-file-creation-updation-of